# Обход определение selenium-webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hide

Браузеры Chrome, Chromium 80,81, python3.8.

Есть сайт для проверки на бота.
[Antibot](https://bot.sannysoft.com)

При использовании selenium проверку на webdriver не проходит.

[image: Detect webdriver]

Каким способом можно обойти определение webdriver?

Использованные способы (без результатов):

1. редактирование переменной $cdc в файле chromedriver
2. `options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])`
3. `driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
   "source":"""Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})"""
       })`

На сколько я заметил данный способ определения появился недавно. Пару месяцев назад тест проходил без проблем.

Мой код для теста

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=./chromeprofile")
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(f"./chromedriver", options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
            "source": """
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
              get: () => undefined
            })
          """
        })#navigator.webdriver = undefined
driver.get('https://bot.sannysoft.com')
time.sleep(225)
driver.quit()
```

В продолжение: если запустить Chrome в дебаг режиме, так же определяется WebDriver.

Answer (score 2):

В общем нашел ответ, нужно выполнить данный скрипт.

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
     "source": """
          const newProto = navigator.__proto__
          delete newProto.webdriver
          navigator.__proto__ = newProto
          """
    })
```

Проверил на [Antibot](https://bot.sannysoft.com)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как сделать тоже самое для Firefox? А то выдает ошибку `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'execute_cdp_cmd'`

Comment: Для Firefox решение такое: `profile.set_preference('dom.webdriver.enabled', False)`.