# Не могу Авторизоваться в Gmal с помощи Selenium c#. "Не удалось войти в аккаунт Возможно, этот браузер или приложение небезопасны."

Tags: c#, selenium, gmail

*Начал изучать Selenium на C#. Решил открыть сначала браузер Chrome и авторизоваться в Gmail.*

И после ввода почты уже выходит ошибка: "**Не удалось войти в аккаунт
Возможно, этот браузер или приложение небезопасны.
Попробуйте сменить браузер. Если вы уже используете поддерживаемый браузер, обновите страницу и попробуйте войти ещё раз.**"

Это именно после ввода Email, боюсь представить что будет после ввода пароля, наверное опять какие то проверки.

Код который писал:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"E:\Users\Professional\Desktop\BrowserAutonoumick\BrowserAutonomick\BrowserAutonomick\");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=ru&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail&service=mail&ec=GAlAFw&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession");
    }
```

В этом коде тот что выше, я только захожу на ссылку авторизации почты Gmail. И вручную ввожу данные.
Даже при в ручном воде все равно такая ошибка.
Пробовал менять браузеры, а это **Opera, Chrome, Firefox**.

**Прошу вашей помощи!** Ибо я уже не знаю что с этим делать, но сдаваться не хочу! А блин, изучать Selenium не охота когда вот просто так забил на ошибку, изучая и думая что уже простую задачу выполнить не смог...
А так на другие почты например Mail.ru могу авторизоваться.

Comment: [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides?hl=ru) - вам не нужен браузер, чтобы забраться в Gmail почту. Гугл намеренно блочит всех ботов, обойти блокировку скорее всего можно, но я не знаю как.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можете уточнить почему не нужен браузер? Либо вы хотите сказать что он не поможет?
Я вот знаю одну программу, возможно и вы знаете программу под названием BAS - BrowserAutomationStudio. То вот там по моему тоже используется Selenium, и там можно спокойно например ввести ссылку Gmail, а потом и входит, даже я уже так пробовал делать, даже каптчи нет. Меня жутко заинтересовала такая техника, вот и решил попробовать написать подобное на языке программирование c#. Но как видно не получилось.
Видел проблему на их форуме, то сказали что на подобный вопрос не ответят.

Comment: Все сводится к тому, что вам нужно обойти защиту гугла от ботов. Как это сделать - я не знаю.

Comment: @aepot, то есть все таки нужно как то защиту обходить? И это не связанно с браузером или с чем то другим. Просто как я понимаю Gmail как то узнает что у меня браузер находиться под автономным управлением. И я вот думаю, можно ли это как то исправить?

Comment: Иемнно так, вам скорее всего нужно смотреть, какие запросы отправляет браузер, когда вы управляете им вручну, и какие запросы он отправляет при управлении через драйвер. Возможно какие-то куки отсутствуют, или еще что-то.

Comment: Хох! Спасибо за такую интересную информацию, думаю у меня уже появилась надежа. А можете ли вы мне немного рассказать как это проверить? А то в этом деле я не давно и растерянный.

Comment: Ну либо в инспекторе браузера лог сети смотреть, либо через Fiddler снифать трафик (вроде он такое может).

Comment: Хорошо. Буду сейчас что то пробовать делать. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: раз у вас Firefox, то копайте в сторону profile.SetPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled", false)

Comment: @vitidev, спасибо! Буду пробовать, а то все пробую и пробую но пока что без результатов.

Comment: На  python с этим отлично авторизуется. А без этого пишет про опасность. Проверил только что.

Comment: Хох! Я конечно не изучал Python, но попробую ради интереса, так как все таки нужно выяснить что данную проблему можно решить. Спасибо.

Comment: питон тут не причем. он просто был под рукой. селениум помечает, что браузер работает через драйвер и в случае с firefox проблема решается через [dom.webdriver.enabled](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234446/191496). А в случае хрома через [Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1117483/191496)

Comment: Т.е мне где то это прописать нужно как я понял? Именно в коде c#.

Comment: Это прописывается в профайле, который передается конструктору FirefoxDriver.

Answer (score 0):

Раньше у людей работал способ с авторизацией в Google через сторонний сайт, например, этот. Но у меня в феврале 2021 года такой способ не сработал.

У меня была такая же ошибка авторизации со старым аккаунтом (2017 года). Я не смог её решить на старом аккаунте, но зато смог войти в новый аккаунт.
Не знаю, насколько важны мои действия или нужен просто новый аккаунт. Но я сделал примерно следующее:

- запустил chrome с Selenium (у меня webdriver php)
- при запуске chrome я указал папку для хранения профиля user-data-dir= (не пишу команду, так как у меня php)
- создал аккаунт google с указанием телефона (пробовал ввести телефон на старом аккаунте, ничего не поменялось)
- в настройках аккаунта гугл - безопасность включил "Less secure app access" ON (разрешил авторизацию менее безопасным приложениям)
- Предоставил новому аккаунту доступ к старому аккаунту (google ads).
- В gmail можно скачать всю почту + сделать переадресацию новых писем + ответ от имени старого аккаунта.

Только сегодня я столкнулся с этой задачей. Честно, не знаю как долго проработает новый аккаунт (может через неделю вылезет старая ошибка). И поэтому я планирую использоать для своих задач другой софт - Puppeteer (https://pptr.dev/). Он, вроде, управляет хромом по-другому принципу и я видел свежее сообщение о его работоспособности.

Comment: Вау! Спасибо за такую подробную инструкцию. Думаю данный способ мне поможет, но пока что не проверял. 
И можете ли вы немного рассказать о софте Puppeteer? Я как понял это программа которая автономно управляет браузером? Но если так то как мне подключить эту программу через C# в будущим? Что бы например как раз через него все делать.